# UITableView section headers UI has changed

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a UITableViewController but when I try to add sections (programmatically), they show up like this:

[image]

instead of looking like this....

[image]

Does anyone know why there is a sudden change in the way sections headers are displayed?

Comment: add your code where you add section headers programmatically & where you set header height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it would appear your Table View style is set to Plain when you actually want it set to Grouped.

Plain:
[image]

Grouped:
[image]

If you are creating your Table View in Interface Builder, then just set the Style property as shown in the screenshots.

If you are creating your Table View in code you need to set the style when you init the tableView, assuming a UITableView property named tableView and that the tableView should be sized to match the viewController's view.

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style: UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```